# String to Bool Conversion ... works in 4 bit but not 8 bit

Tags: php

Trying to put together a php program that reads a 'menu' integer variable (passed through the URL)  that converts it to a binary string ... then reads each Boolean in the string and adds it to an array.

Works fine for 4-bit (albeit perhaps not very efficient) .... but won't work for 8-bit?

```
<?php

$menubin = decbin($_GET['menu']);

$menulen = strlen($menubin)-1;


for($x=$menulen; $x > -1; $x--)

{

$array = $menulen-$x;

$menubool[$array] = substr($menubin,$x,1);

}

if($menubool[0] == '1') { ... }

if($menubool[1] == '1') { ... }

if($menubool[2] == '1') { ... }

if($menubool[3] == '1') { ... }

if($menubool[4] == '1') { ... }

if($menubool[5] == '1') { ... }

if($menubool[6] == '1') { ... }

if($menubool[7] == '1') { ... }

?>
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but you could simplify the whole bunch of `if` lines with just: `if (in_array(1, $menubool)) {}`.

Comment: There a 10 kinds of people in the world. Those who understand binary and those who not.

Comment: Solved it. it's a string length problem. Cheers Amal, will look into making the ifs more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `$menubin` string looks something like `0100`. This can be achieved with [bitwise operands](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) and a switch statement. This approach will give you some flexibility and allow you to select menu items arbitrarily.

```
<?php
//string of selections
$string = "1011";
// result of bitshift on string
$bits = 0;

for($i = strlen($string); $i >= 0; $i -= 1){
    $bits += (int)$string[$i] << $i;
}

// arbitrarily make selections and cases as you add menu items
switch($bits) {
         case 1: 
             echo "menu item 1";
             break;
         case 2: 
             echo "menu item 2";
             break;
         case 4: 
             echo "menu item 3";
             break;
         case 8: 
             echo "menu item 4";
             break;
         case 13:
             echo "menu item 1, 3 and 4";
         break;

}

?>
```

Comment: `1011` is not 13, it's 11 - you are are reading (or writing) the bit pattern backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$int = 37; // for example
$bits = array();
$str = str_pad(decbin($int),8,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    for ($i=0; $i<=7; $i++){
        $bits[7-$i] = substr($str,$i,1);
    }
var_dump($bits);
```

Then just access the bits of the array as you require for your menu options.

Your initial problem was that `decbin` doesn't return the correct string length, hence the padding function above.

In your case, 64 would return `1000000` and not `01000000`